# Typescript : create a type extending from primitive type?

Tags: angularjs, string, typescript, types, primitive

In my angular project, I want to create a custom type extending from string. my case is I want to create a "ID" type to separate string from idstring.

```
let str = String("tutu");
let id = ID("ec1s69azs");

this.service.getUserById(str) => doesn't compile;
this.service.getUserById(id) => compile;
```

In the future, I may want to add id validator in "ID" type

I was wondering if its possible because I've tried many "hacks" but none give me the result I want.

```
class ObjectID extends String {
}


export type ID = ObjectID;
```

or

```
interface StringConstructor {
  new(value?: any): String;
  (value?: any): string;
  readonly prototype: String;
  fromCharCode(...codes: number[]): string;
}

export type ID = StringConstructor;
```

Comment: Why do you need to validate ID into ID class ?

Comment: To validate id fomat, for example I will be able to valide ids from my server.

Comment: I was thinking you have some logic in ID format (e.g. if ID has some letters, user will be able to do something).
But client is UI so client must trust data from your server, and server must not trust to data from client side. Seems you have a mistake in general idea.

Comment: You're right, but it's more for debug purpose and programmation auto-completion and implementation and it was just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think you need to extends `string`, you can use branded types to achieve the desired result.

```
type ObjectID =  string & { __type: 'Id'}
function ID(n: string): ObjectID{
    return n as any;
}


// Usage
function getUserById(id: ObjectID) {

}

getUserById(ID("1")); //ok
getUserById("1");  // error
```

You need to define a helper function to create instances of the type or use casting, but the call site will give errors if you pass a simple string.

This [article](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/01/15/typescript-flexible-nominal-typing/) has a bit more of a discussion on the topic. Also the typescript compiler uses this approach for [paths](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/8e8e879fc22e080f0c8fe69a73921899ab062c3f/src/compiler/types.ts#L54)